# Итерация с подсписками

Tags: python, list

Есть список

```
[[-0.56, 0.08], [-0.54, 0.09], [-0.52, 0.1], [-0.5, 0.11]]
```

Все значения в нем float

Есть функция

```
def Area(list1):
    s = 0
    for i in list1:
        s += (list1[i][0])*(list1[i+1][1]) - (list1[i+1][0])*(list1[i][1])
    return s
```

Но она совсем не хочет работать с подсписками, выдает

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

Как решить или обойти?
При том такая проблема наблюдается только при цикле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В цикле `for i in list1: ...` параметр `i` принимает значения подсписков, а не индексов. Вам достаточно поменять цикл на такой:

```
for i in range(len(list1)-1):
    ...
```

Конечно, итерацию с индексами обычно делают через `enumerate(list1)`, но я пока сходу не могу придумать, как через `enumerate` итерироваться до предпоследнего элемента (без сечений списка или других еще более извращенных методов).

Comment: Жаль я не заметил Ваш комментарий раньше, не нужно было бы самому до этого додумываться. 
Спасибо за ответ, все равно (:

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующее решение:

```
list = [[-0.56, 0.08], [-0.54, 0.09], [-0.52, 0.1], [-0.5, 0.11]]

def area(list):
s = 0
i = 0
while i < len(list) - 1:
    s += (list[i][0])*(list[i+1][1]) - (list[i+1][0])*(list[i][1])
    i += 1
return s
```

В Вашем случае i - элемент списка list1 - тоже список. В предлагаемом мной решении i - индекс, число.

Comment: "Мне кажется, проблема в том, что i принимает значения от 0 до len(list)" - ошибаетесь. Если попробовать вывести `for i in list1: print(i)`, то вы увидите, что выводятся подсписки, а не индексы. Об этом и говорит ошибка, указанная в вопросе ("индексы должны быть целыми числами, а не списками"). Невозможность прочитать по индексу `i+1` для последнего элемента списка - это уже другая ошибка, с которой автор вопроса на данном этапе еще не столкнулся.

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо. Редактирую ответ.

Comment: @y-v Да, до ошибки с невозможностью вылезти за предел списка я еще не дошел.
Ссылаясь на Ваше решение, я решил проблему так:
`for i in range(len(list_of_koordinates)-1)`
Что-то совсем забыл такой способ

Answer (score 0):

```
def add(_list):
    lst = _list[0]
    for a in _list[1:]:
        yield lst[0] * a[1] - a[0] * lst[1]
        lst = a

print(sum(add([[-0.56, 0.08], [-0.54, 0.09], [-0.52, 0.1], [-0.5, 0.11]])))
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы крайне благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к коду.

Comment: ИМХО, оверинженеринг для такой простой задачи.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [[-0.56, 0.08], [-0.54, 0.09], [-0.52, 0.1], [-0.5, 0.11]]
print(sum(l[q][0] * l[q+1][1] - l[q+1][0] * l[q][1] for q in range(len(l)-1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Идиоматичный способ организовать подобный цикл в Питоне не использует обращения по индексам, а работает с элементами напрямую:

```
>>> points = [[-0.56, 0.08], [-0.54, 0.09], [-0.52, 0.1], [-0.5, 0.11]]
>>> sum(x1*y2 - x2*y1 for (x1,y1), (x2,y2) in zip(points, points[1:]))
-0.021600000000000001
```